# C++ Creating an atomic function

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, mutex, atomic

```
void foo ( Bar* bar , void(Bar::*qux)(void) )
{
    if ( bar )
    {
        bar->qux();
    }
}
```

The problem is:

1. `bar` can be deleted **after** the check by another thread.
2. I can not add a mutex member to `Bar` in order to lock it.

Thus I wonder, if I can tell the processor to run this function atomically, and how would I do so? I've spent way to much time on Google, but found no understandable manuals...

P.S. Debian, gcc , Boost **NOT** allowed, C++11 **IS** allowed.

Comment: please also show the code where `bar` can be deleted.

Comment: @user2k5 `delete bar;` I don't get it, what do you expect to see...

Comment: is the deleter only accessible by 1 thread or multiple threads? If it is, then the deleter also needs a synchronization, together with `foo` function. Actually it is better to mention what you want to achieve, rather than plain codes.

Comment: Strictly speaking a mutex does not have to be part of the class to be used.

Comment: I don't think that running this function atomically will do anything about the possibility that the object might be deleted in another thread... Atomicity in a function primarily assures that it won't be interrupted by something else, and places no restrictions on what might be going on elsewhere. A mutex protecting the object is what is needed to prevent the scenario you describe.

Comment: @twalberg if this functions runs atomically there won't be ANY errors. Since it's guaranteed that `bar` won't be deleted.

Comment: How can that be? If bar is deleted in another function, then it doesnt matter what you do in this function, unless both use the same mutex.

Comment: @Brady it seems to me, you don't get the problem. If statement returns true, then `bar` is being deleted from another thread, then `bar->qux();` tries to operate with some members of `Bar` but they do not longer exist and the program fails in segmentation fault.

Comment: @Kolyunya Running function `A` atomically makes absolutely no guarantees about what function `B` running in another thread on another core is doing with data, even data that `A` might be using. It only guarantees that function `A` won't be interrupted. Atomicity is not the same thing as mutual exclusion.

Comment: @Kolyunya Yes and if you just guarantee this function to be run atomically (thus not getting interrupted in any way), nobody actually guarantees the the deleting thread is not run in parallel to this function. `foo` still runs atomically in that nobody does interrupt it, but on an actual multicore system the deleting thread can just run in parallel to `foo` which doesn't violate `foo`'s atomicity.

Comment: Ok, now I get it... multiple cores... well, I'm gonna derive `Bar` from `BarBase` which will have a mutex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of atomic methods doesnt exist in C++ like it does in Java, where you can define a method as synchronized. The closest you can get to that in C++ would be to create a ScopedMutex class as follows:

```
class ScopedMutex {
public:
    ScopedMutex(pthread_mutex *m) : theMutex_(m) {pthread_mutex_lock(theMutex_);}
    ~ScopedMutex() { pthread_mutex_unlock(theMutex_); }
    // Add appropriate copy constructors and operator=() to disallow mutex copy
    // Or consider passing in a reference
private:
    pthread_mutex *theMutex_;
};
```

Then use it like this in your function:

```
void foo ( Bar* bar , void(Bar::*qux)(void) )
{
    ScopedMutex m(&aMutex); // This mutex must be defined/initialized elsewhere

    if ( bar )
    {
        bar->qux();
    }

    // The ScopedMutex goes out of scope when the function does,
    // thus releasing the lock
}
```

But this wont do you any good unless you use the same mutex in every other method that uses the bar object.

Scoped Mutex are especially useful when you have a function with complicated logic where there are several return statements, so you dont have to manually unlock the mutex it will be unlocked when the function goes out of scope.

Comment: -1, Your lock is copyable, but it should not be. Using pthread_mutex & theMutex_; (Reference instead of pointer) will solve the problem

Comment: @nogard, I updated the answer with suggestions to avoid said copy. Although its technically possible to copy the mutex and it should be avoided, I cant imagine anyone ever wanting to copy a scoped mutex. What would be the use case to do so?

Comment: there is no use case for scoped mutex, that's why it must be explicitly disabled. However copying of locks make sence for other types of locks (shared_lock). See here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html

Comment: It seems you didn't upgrade the answer. I removed -1 anyway

Comment: @nogard, I was referring to what would be the use case of copying a ScopedMutex.

Comment: Yes, I've already replied: no use case for scoped mutex, so must be explicitly disabled

Comment: @nogard, Ugg, sorry, Im trying to do too many things at once, too many context switches isnt only bad for computers :)

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use a smart pointer with shared ownership semantics (e.g. `shared_ptr`, `intrusive_ptr`) to make sure the object stays alive as long as you refer to it.

Comment: Ok, but how does it work? I bet it uses some atomic-mechanisms inside?

Comment: They normally use atomic integer increment and decrement to update the reference counter in a thread-safe manner.

Answer (score 4):

You want to temporarily share ownership of the object, in order to prevent another thread from deleting it. This is a job for `shared_ptr`, using `weak_ptr` to allow deletion when we don't need to access it:

```
void foo ( std::weak_ptr<Bar> weak_bar , void(Bar::*qux)(void) ) 
{
    if (std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar = weak_bar.lock())
    {
        // We now share ownership of the object - it won't be deleted
        bar->qux();
    }

    // We have released ownership - it can now be deleted
}
```

Of course, you still need synchronisation if multiple threads need to access the object; this only solves the problem of deletion specified in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but no. C++ doesn't have anything to support that. You don't necessarily need to add the mutex to `Bar`, but to avoid it, you'll probably need a wrapper around `Bar`, or something on that order.

Comment: Sad... very sad... I probably would derive `Bar` from `BarBase`, which will have a mutex. Is this a correct solution?

Comment: @Kolyunya: If you can add a base class to `Bar`, then why on earth can't you add a member? That would be much less weird.

Comment: @Kolyunya I don't see how adding a mutex to `Bar` will help at all. When and how would it be used? If it's a member of the `Bar` class, it will be destructed together with the instance so still can't be used in e.g. `foo`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `foo` will lock the mutex and another thread will try to lock it too before deleting `bar`. It's that easy.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, the whole 'story' is about designing an `observer` pattern. It's more use-able to derive listener from `Listener` than to add a mutex member to each listener

Comment: @Kolyunya Ah of course, seems I had a case of [The Complicator](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Complicator_0x27_s_Gloves.aspx).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg if you have a better solution, I'd listen to it attentively.