# Multiple threads and mutexes

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am very new to Linux programming so bear with me. I have 2 thread type that perform different operations so I want each one to have it's own mutex. Here is the code I am using , is it good ? If not why ?

```
static pthread_mutex_t cs_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t cs_mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITALIZER;

void * Thread1(void * lp)
{
    int * sock = (int*)lp;
    char buffer[2024];

    int bytecount = recv(*sock, buffer, 2048, 0);
    while (0 == 0)
    {
        if ((bytecount ==0) || (bytecount == -1))
        {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&cs_mutex);

                  //Some uninteresting operations witch plays with set 1 of global variables;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cs_mutex);
        }
    }
}

void * Thread2(void * lp)
{   
    while (0 == 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&cs_mutex2);
            //Some uninteresting operations witch plays with some global variables;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cs_mutex2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(0 == 0)` is very odd. `while(1)` would be more traditional.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain they have the same effect tough

Comment: I don't think there's enough code here to know whether what you're doing makes sense or not.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am asking wether the mutex are doing there job in the actual state

Comment: @opc0de: Right, but we don't know what their job is because there's no actual code that runs under the protection of the mutex. So it's almost impossible to answer.

Comment: @opc0de, `while( 0==1 ? 42 : 1 )` works the same way too, but `while(true)` is much more readable ;)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i am just modifing a global array.I have more than 3-4 threads for each thread type running so I am preventing the alteration of the data in the array

Comment: Have more than one thread that always holds the same mutex is definitely not good.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i think that too. So any fix how can I initalize mutexes dinamically ?

Comment: @opc0de: That's not the issue. The issue is that if you have two pieces of code that can never run at the same time, there's no point in putting them in two threads. All you do is force the scheduler to make extra context switches.

Comment: @David Schwarz - I think your comment is sufficiently important to be worth expanding as an answer. At the level of the question I suspect that the implications of "always" will not be understood - indeed maybe I didn't understand either, I think you're considering starvation scenarios?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, a mutex is not thread related.
It ensures that a critical area is only accessed by a single thread. 
So if u have some shared areas, like processing the same array by multiple threads, then you must ensure exclusive access for this area.
That means, you do not need a mutex for each thread. You need a mutex for the critical area.

Answer (score 6):

If you only have one driver, there is no advantage to having two cars. Your `Thread2` code can only make useful progress while holding `cs_mutex2`. So there's no point to having more than one thread running that code. Only one thread can hold the mutex at a time, and the other thread can do no useful work.

So all you'll accomplish is that occasionally the thread that doesn't hold the mutex will try to run and have to wait for the other. And occasionally the thread that does hold the mutex will try to release and re-acquire it and get pre-empted by the other.

This is a completely pointless use of threads.

Comment: Each thread type handles several TCP / IP Connections if i have 3 connections on port 8030 then i have 3 threads of type 1 if i have 4 connections on port 8050 i have 5 threads of type 2. Each types handle 2 diffrent global data sets so if 2 threads of type 1 modify an array simultaneous than it will be a problem. Hope you understand why the threads are necesary.

Answer (score 3):

I see three problems here. There's a question your infinite loop, another about your intention in having multiple threads, and there's a future maintainability "gotcha" lurking.

First

```
int bytecount = recv(*sock, buffer, 2048, 0);
while (0 == 0)
```

Is that right? You read some stuff from a socket, and start an infinite loop without ever closing the socket? I can only assume that you do some more reading in the loop, but in which case you are waiting for an external event while holding the mutex. In general that's a  bad pattern limiting your concurrency. A possibly pattern is to have one thread reading the data and then passing the read data to other threads which do the processing.

Next, you have two different sets of resources each protected by their own mutex. You then intend  to have a set of Threads for each resource. But each thread has the pattern

```
   take mutex
       lots of processing
   release mutex
       tiny window (a few machine instructions)
   take mutex again
        lots of processing
   release mutex
        next tiny window
```

There's virtually no opportunity for two threads to work in parallel. I question whether your have need for multiple threads for each resource.

Last there's a potential maintenance issue. I'm just pointing this out for future reference, I don't think you need to do anything right now. You have two functions, intended for use by two threads, but in the end they are just functions that can be called by anyone. If later maintenance results in those functions (or refactored subsets of the functions) then you could get two threads

```
    take mutex 1
    take mutex 2
```

and the other

```
    take mutex 2
    take mutex 1
```

Bingo: deadlock.

Not an easy problem to avoid, but at the very least one can aid the maintainer by careful naming choices and refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is correct, however please note 2 things:

1. It is not exception safe. If exception is thrown from `Some uninteresting operations` then your mutex will be never unlocked -> deadlock
2. You could also consider using std::mutex or boost::mutex instead of raw mutexes. For mutex locking it's better to use boost::mutex::scoped_lock (or std:: analog with modern compiler)

   ```
   void test()
   {
       // not synch code here
       {
           boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);
           // synchronized code here
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: There's no exception throwing code at the moment, so I'm not sure that is a fair comment. Having said that, using RAII is a very good idea. +1

Comment: Why would std::mutex or boost::mutex be better than using a raw mutex? I agree with you about the scoped mutex.

Comment: @Brady: Because if you lock std::mutex with scoped_lock it's exception safe. If exception occurs in synchronized section -> stack unwinds -> local variables destroyed (our scoped_lock) -> mutex unlocked from destructor of scoped_lock -> no deadlock. How can you easily do this with raw mutex?

Comment: Im pretty sure "raw mutexes" are exception safe. If you can use boost or c++11, then perhaps its reinventing the wheel, but it can easily be done as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12409002/1158895

Comment: @Brady: Yes, your class is exception safe. But this approach has several disadvantages: 1. you have to write it by yourself for each project. 2. It's not portable 3. It's not known by other developers. Each time they encounter your Mutex they have to look it's documentation. 4. Finally your implementation is not correct, because your lock is copyable.. Why not to profit from standard library? In most cases it's better

Comment: @nogard, I disagree with all of your points except the first and the copyable lock (this point is very picky), and I partly disagree with the first. Have you considered the case that lots of people still cant use boost nor c++11 due to requirements?? In that case, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: @nogard, You still havent given a good reason why the std mutex are better than raw mutex apart from the scoped locking.

Comment: @Brady: I give you the reasons, but you just disagree :) So why std mutex is better: 1. It's cross-platform. 2. You can profit from several standard locks (not just scoped one!) without implementing them for each project.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 *different* sets of data and 2 *different* threads working on these sets -- why do you need mutexes at all? Usually, mutexes are used when you deal with some *shared* piece of data and you don't want two threads to deal with it simultaneously, so you lock it with mutex, do some stuff, unlock.

Comment: I have 2 different thread types but i have 3-4 threads running from every type

Comment: Ah, in this case, it's of course understandable. I could also advise you to check for what functions pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() return. It's always a good style to do checking for return values.

Comment: So I am not having a conflict if 3 threads use the same static mutex ?

Comment: It's a classic example: you have 1 mutex and 3 threads. You do some operation on same data from 3 threads. So from each of your thread you do lock-make_some_stuff-unlock routine. If you locked your mutex and at the same time another thread is trying to lock it, then it suspends and waits for the first thread to unlock it. You also can read about semaphors (more sophisticated mutexes).

Comment: @opc0de, No, there is no conflict. Actually, it must be the same mutex used by all threads concerned, else the code executed by the threads wont be mutually exclusive. Nor is it a problem that the mutex is static.